# Converting a PHP array into C#

Tags: c#, php, arrays

How would I go about converting this PHP array into C#

```
$hiscores = array("Overall",
            "stats" => array(        
                    "Attack", "Defence", "Strength",
                    "Hitpoints", "Ranged", "Prayer",
                    "Magic", "Cooking", "Woodcutting",
                    "Fletching", "Fishing", "Firemaking",
                    "Crafting", "Smithing", "Mining",
                    "Herblore", "Agility", "Thieving",
                    "Slayer", "Farming", "Runecrafting",
                    "Hunter", "Construction", "Summoning",
                    "Dungeoneering"
                    ),
            "minigames" => array(
                    "Duel Tournaments", "Bounty Hunters",
                    "Bounty Hunter Rogues", "Fist of Guthix",
                    "Mobilising Armies", "B.A Attackers",
                    "B.A Defenders", "B.A Healers",
                    "Castle Wars Games", "Conquest"
             )
);
```

I find PHP syntax to be very confusing so I can't tell how I would go about doing this personally.

From what I can tell it would be something like:

```
string[] hiscores = new string["Overall","stats","minigames"]
```

However "stats" and "minigames" don't contain the string likes they do in the PHP code.

I'm also not sure what the "=> array()" means.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with this structure.  Could be a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, could be a custom class, could be something else.  Don't get hung up on a line-by-line conversion between languages.  Implement the functionality in the target language.

Comment: I suggest you to read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP the arrays have a key and a value, this is defined like this:

```
  key => "value"
```

A key can have one ore many items associated whit it.In your example the key had an array of strings associated whit it.

In C# you can do this by using [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Whit an dictionary you can add for example an array of strings to one key. Now you can add an array of minigames to the key mini games. To get the value from the minigame you can do `dictionary["minigame"]`. Notice that the key must exist in the dictionary

Define the dictionary,
the keys will be of type string and the values that are bind to the key will be of type string array so you can add an array of strings to one key.

```
    Dictionary<string, string[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

Add the items to the dictionary:

```
        dictionary.Add("stats", new[]
            {
                "Attack", "Defence", "Strength",
                "Hitpoints", "Ranged", "Prayer",
                "Fletching", "Fishing", "Firemaking",
                "Crafting", "Smithing", "Mining"
            }
        );

        dictionary.Add("minigames", new[]
            {
                "Duel Tournaments", "Bounty Hunters",
                "Bounty Hunter Rogues", "Fist of Guthix",
                "Mobilising Armies", "B.A Attackers",
                "B.A Defenders", "B.A Healers",
                "Castle Wars Games", "Conquest"
            }
        );
```

Getting the items whits are associated whit the `stats` key:

```
        foreach (var value in dictionary["stats"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
```

Getting the items whits are associated whit the `minigames` key:

```
        foreach (var value in dictionary["minigames"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use OrderedDictionary class in .NET to deal with this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
public class MakeList
{
    private List<Model1> models1;
    public MakeList()
    {
        models1 = new List<Model1>
        {
            new Model1
            {
                FirstProp = "Overall",
                SecondProp = new List<String>
                        {
                           "Attack", "Defence", "Strength",
                        "Hitpoints", "Ranged", "Prayer",
                        "Magic", "Cooking", "Woodcutting",
                        "Fletching", "Fishing", "Firemaking",
                        "Crafting", "Smithing", "Mining",
                        "Herblore", "Agility", "Thieving",
                        "Slayer", "Farming", "Runecrafting",
                        "Hunter", "Construction", "Summoning",
                        "Dungeoneering"
                        },
                ThirdProp = new List<String>
                        {
                         "Duel Tournaments", "Bounty Hunters",
                        "Bounty Hunter Rogues", "Fist of Guthix",
                        "Mobilising Armies", "B.A Attackers",
                        "B.A Defenders", "B.A Healers",
                        "Castle Wars Games", "Conquest"
                        }
        }


    };
  }
}
```

With this class that you are going to change to suits your needs:

```
public class Model1
{
    public string FirstProp { get; set; }
    public List<String> SecondProp { get; set; }
    public List<String> ThirdProp { get; set;  }
}
```